# googlesheet gs_new() too slow

Tags: r, data.table, r-googlesheets

I've got a data.table DT with 270 observations of 21 variables. Using GoogleSheet API to write this data.table to Google drive. it takes about ten minutes for the file to be written. Is this normal?? I've tried everything and looked everywhere to see if there is anything wrong with my code, but I just can't find a reason for it to be so slow. It's not the internet connection either.

```
## this takes forever
require(googlesheets)

gs_file <- gs_new( title = 'test', ws_title = 'DATA__test', input = DT, trim = TRUE)
```

I haven't been able to write much larger files as it takes too long! I don't think it should take this long and believe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: this is my experience with this package as well, unfortunately. I think it is just a limitation.

Comment: good to know. helps me stop pulling out my hair.